# ¿Cómo enviar notificaciones con onesignal usando una variable php?

Tags: php, javascript, slim, notificaciones, onesignal

> Quiero enviar notificacion a un usuario de la base de datos, mi api esta hecho con slim framework php, ya tengo hecha la tabla que guarda el id del usuario con su id del dispositivo. Este es mi index.php

```
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'Has recibido una nueva orden'
        );

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'include_player_ids' => array($GLOBALS ['playerID']),
        'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
        'large_icon' =>"ic_launcher_round.png",
        'contents' => $content
    );

    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                               'Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxx'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Algún error que te genere? O cual es la variable que quieres agregar?

Comment: 'include_player_ids' => array($GLOBALS ['playerID']), deseo que sea dinámico, es decir, que se le envie la notificacion a dispositivos especificos sin estar agregando los id_dispositivo manualmente en la api, quiero que los id_dispositivo de mi tabla sean agregados a include player id

Comment: Pues puedes usar foreach para listar y concatenar cada `id_dispositivo` en un array y pasárselo a `include_player_ids`

Comment: Listo eso funcionó, pero que sucede si quiero enviarle ahora a un usuario específico de la base de datos la cual ya tiene un id_dispositivo

Comment: Pues puedes hacer un filtro a ese array, para que solo muestre el `id_dispositivo` al cual quieres enviar esa notificación.

Comment: A lo mejor podrías probar con un array de un solo elemento